# jQuery ":hover" doesn't appear to be working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

If you look at this page:

http://bbdesign.com/berksfoods.com/retail-deli-meats-roast-beef.htm

Hold your mouse over the Products button at the top-left (to the right of the big logo) and move down over the menu that appears. If you move off of the Products button and the drop-menu, it disappears. This is as intended.

The big logo is a transparent PNG. I have a jQuery event "mouseleave" on the Products button and the drop-down menu that causes the menu to disappear when the mouse is no longer over them.

If the mouse goes over the logo, of course, that means the menu closes (since it isn't a child of the container for "mouseleave"). I solved this by adding the following:

```
if (!$('img#logo').is(':hover')){
    $(this).children('div#menu1bg').slideUp(200);
}
```

In other words, if the "mouseleave" event is triggered, first check to make sure the mouse isn't over the logo (img#logo). If it is over the logo, don't close the menu.

This seems to work nicely, except it doesn't work at all in Internet Explorer. Is there a known issue with ':hover' and that browser? Or is there some other way of coding the same thing that will work better on all browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, ideally I need this to work in any recent version of IE, since all sorts of users will be hitting the website.

Comment: I meant, which version(s) of IE are showing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your jQuery, it's in your CSS.  IE isn't popular with supporting CSS tags, but it should work in IE7.  In any case, try adding a strict `!DOCTYPE`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

*This DTD contains all HTML elements and attributes, but does NOT INCLUDE presentational or deprecated elements (like font). Framesets are not allowed.*

IE6- lets `:hover` behave on `a` elements, though.  Wrap your logo in an `a` tag, it might work.

[image: IE CSS support]

If you look at this, there's not much you *can* do.

Actually, in any case, use JQuery's [`.mouseLeave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) and [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) functions:

```
$('img#logo').mouseLeave(function()
{
    $(this).children('div#menu1bg').slideUp(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I tried getting rid of the ':hover' altogether, and instead put the element inside the event that I am testing for mouseLeave. I put position:absolute and positioned it so it appears outside of the button, but in the same place it was before. Thanks!

Comment: @BBDesign You're welcome, I hope you get it to appear in the button and wish you luck